# Missing order of display in console when using scanner in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

My code is,

```
public class trueFalse {

public static void main(String[] args){
    String sz = null;
    do{
        String s = null;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter an integer");
        int myint = keyboard.nextInt();
        if(myint<0){
            System.out.println("Lessthan zero");
        }
        else
        {    
            s = getVal(myint);
            System.out.println("Value :: "+s);
        }
            Scanner keyboard2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Do you want to continue ? (YES/no)");
            sz = keyboard2.next();
        }while(sz.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
}

public static String getVal(int num){
    return num == 0 ? "ZERO" : "One+";   
}

}
```

When I execute the display order in console as follows,

> enter an integer
>
> Value :: One+
>
> Do you want to continue ? (YES/no)
>
> 1      *#[this one I entered second line in console]*
>
> yes
>
> enter an integer
>
> Value :: One+
>
> Do you want to continue ? (YES/no)
>
> 3
>
> enter an integer
>
> yes

Where I made mistake ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use two Scanners. You can replace `sz = keyboard2.next();` with `sz = keyboard.nextLine();` Also, move the Scanner outside your `do-while` loop.

Also, you'll have to add `keyboard.nextLine();` after `int myint = keyboard.nextInt();`

Here is the corrected code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Move Scanner outside of do-while */
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = null;
    String sz = null;
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter Integer Value: ");
        /* Integer Parsing */
        String str = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Entered Integer: " + str);
        int myint = Integer.parseInt(str);

        if(myint < 0){
            System.out.println("Value Less Than Zero!");
        }
        else
        {    
            s = getVal(myint);
            System.out.println("Value :: " + s);
        }
        System.out.println("Do you want to continue ? (yes/no)");
        sz = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Entered Value: " + sz);
    } while(sz.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
}

public static String getVal(int num){
    return num == 0 ? "ZERO" : "One+";   
}
```

Output:

```
Enter Integer Value: 
Entered Integer: 1
Value :: One+
Do you want to continue ? (yes/no)
Entered Value: yes
Enter Integer Value: 
Entered Integer: 2
Value :: One+
Do you want to continue ? (yes/no)
Entered Value: yes
Enter Integer Value: 
Entered Integer: 3
Value :: One+
Do you want to continue ? (yes/no)
Entered Value: yes
Enter Integer Value: 
Entered Integer: 4
Value :: One+
Do you want to continue ? (yes/no)
Entered Value: no
```

Comment: I have replaced still I am getting output as, `enter an integer
Value :: One+
Do you want to continue ? (YES/no)
1
yes
enter an integer
Value :: One+
Do you want to continue ? (YES/no)
5
yes
enter an integer
Lessthan zero
Do you want to continue ? (YES/no)
-1
`

Comment: Check the corrected code snippet and the attached output.

Comment: I have checked it almost work but when I enter an integer as one again the same problem, `5
Entered Integer: 5
Value :: One+
Do you want to continue ? (YES/no)
yes
Entered Value: yes
enter an integer
Entered Integer: 1
Value :: One+
Do you want to continue ? (YES/no)
1
yes
Entered Value: yes
enter an integer
-1
Entered Integer: -1
Lessthan zero
Do you want to continue ? (YES/no)
yes
Entered Value: yes
enter an integer
Entered Integer: 1
Value :: One+
Do you want to continue ? (YES/no)
1`

Comment: ooh, is it problem in my system ? it's wroking for u nice... I am using LinuxMint 32b os